# Is it possible to download an app and install it on iPhone/iPad by using Finder

Tags: macos, ios, finder, ios-appstore, ipados

Actually, after updating to Catalina iTunes is divided into Music macOS application and Finder abilities. So for backup and etc, we should use Finder, now I want to know:

**Is it possible to download an app from App Store and install it on iPhone/iPad by using Finder**?

Comment: There can be substantial overlap between SO and AD so just take those discussions to [meta] when anyone has doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you send your iOS device’s UUID to an app’s developer, and they send you an Ad Hoc signed version of the app, then you can install that version of the app on that device via drag-and-drop using the Finder.

If you install (or update) an app on the iOS device using Apple’s Configurator 2, and keep a copy of that app before it is auto-deleted from your Mac, then you can (re)install that app on that device via Finder drag and drop.

The Finder alone has no connection to Apple’s iOS App Store (AFAIK). So, strictly, using the macOS Finder only, on Catalina, no.

Answer (score 4):

No.

Firstly, you can't access the iOS App Store on MacOS, so you can't download iOS apps onto your Mac. You can of course download apps from the Mac App Store, but they won't work on iOS.

Secondly, there's no general mechanism to 'side-load' apps onto iOS (well, there might be, but not without jail-breaking your iPad).

There may be methods that require the co-operation of the developer, or Enterprise device management tools.

Comment: Dear bro, thanks for your answer, , I'm developer, I know an application for macOS doesn't work on another OS like iOS, really thanks fo your answer, I leave an upvote 

Comment: “There’s no general mechanism to ‘side-load” apps into iOS” I don’t know whether you count XCode and the developer tools? I don’t know how difficult it is to do so  without having the source code however.

Comment: @11684 My point exactly: if you've got the developer on side, then that's a different case from end-user.

Comment: @benwiggy sorry I should clarify; the developer tools are freely available.

Comment: @11684, yes, but as you point out, having Xcode won't help you without the source code. Most people don't have access to source code for App Store apps.!

Comment: Most people don’t have access to the binary either, I don’t see why having the source code is less likely. Side-loading via XCode is possible for open-source apps and given the binary it should also be possible to decompile (it won’t be legible but you can use XCode to recompile it for your device). It might also be possible to get XCode to accept a binary as part of a target so it transfers it to your device too but that probably wouldn’t be easier. Maybe you can swap out the compiled binary in between build phases.